# Equivalent norm in Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $\rho\in H^{1}(0,\pi)$ be a function, and consider the functional
$$
I(\rho)=\bigg(\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sqrt{\rho^2(t)+\dot\rho^2(t)}\,dt}\bigg)^2.
$$ 
I'm asking if it is equivalent to the norm 
$$
\lVert \rho \rVert_{H^1}=\lVert \rho \rVert_{L^2}+\lVert \dot\rho \rVert_{L^2}  
$$
on $H^{1}(0,\pi)$. Obviously $I(\rho)\leq \lVert \rho \rVert_{H^1}^2$, i'm asking if the other inequalities holds.

Comment: Just a note it probably will take some justification that $\sqrt{\rho^2 + \dot{\rho}^2} \in L^1$, but since $(0,\pi)$ doesn't contain sets of arbitrarily large measure we have $L^1 \subset L^{1 / 2}$ it seems pretty clear.

Comment: Maybe i'm making a mistake or i don't know enough propriety of the space $L^p$, but i don't understan how can i conclude the equivalence between the norm since $L^1\subset L^{1/2}$

Comment: I'm not saying the norms are equivalent, I'm just showing you how to show that the integrand is indeed integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, you are asking if $\sqrt{I(\rho)}$ is equivalent to $\|\rho\|_{H^1}$. As you noted, $\sqrt{I(\rho)}$ is dominated by   $\|\rho\|_{H^1}$. However, the converse fails.

Consider $\rho(x)=\sqrt{x+\epsilon}$. Since $\rho'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x+\epsilon}}$, we have $\|\rho\|_{H^1}\to\infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

On the other hand, $\sqrt{I(\rho)}$ stays bounded as $\epsilon\to 0$:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sqrt{\rho^2(t)+\dot\rho^2(t)}\,dt}
\le \int_{0}^{\pi}{\sqrt{\pi+\epsilon + \frac{1}{ 4(x+\epsilon)} }\,dt} = O(1)
$$
since the singularity at $x=0$ is like $1/\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

The functional $\sqrt{I(\rho)}$ cannot be equivalent to the norm $\|\rho\|_{H^1}$ becuase the latter cannot be equivalent to the norm
$$
\|\rho\|_{W^{1,1}}=\|\rho\|_{L^1}+\|\dot{\rho}\|_{L^1}\,.
$$ 
More precisely, due to an obvious fact
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\rho|+|\dot{\rho}|)\leqslant\sqrt{|\rho|^2+|\dot{\rho}|^2}
\leqslant(|\rho|+|\dot{\rho}|)
$$
holds the following inequality
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\|\rho\|_{W^{1,1}}\leqslant\sqrt{I(\rho)}
\leqslant\|\rho\|_{W^{1,1}}\,, 
$$
implying the equivalence of $\sqrt{I(\rho)}$ to the norm $\|\rho\|_{W^{1,1}}$ which is apparently weaker than the norm $\|\rho\|_{W^{1,2}}=\|\rho\|_{H^1}$.